# Wp7 clear canvas value

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas

I am using canvas to add image programatically.

for example:

```
Image image1=new image1();
Image image2=new image1();

            var left = new BitmapImage();
            left.UriSource = new Uri("images/box.png", UriKind.Relative);
            image1.Source = left;
            image2.Source = left;

ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Add(image1);
ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Add(image2);
```

First time enter the loop Add Image to canvas. second time i want to clear canvas.

and again add different images same canvas.

Is this possible wp7.

tell some idea to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Clear();
```

This will empty the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply change the `Source` property of the images you already added?